# Rails : double association with same Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, model

I created a double "Synonym" association with the same Word model as following:

```
class Synonym < ApplicationRecord   
    belongs_to :word_origin, :class_name => "Word"
    belongs_to :word_synonym, :class_name => "Word"
end
```

Here is my Word model:

```
class Word < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :word_synonyms, :class_name => 'Word', :foreign_key => 'word_synonym_id', dependent: :destroy
  has_many :word_origins, :class_name => 'Word', :foreign_key => 'word_origin_id', dependent: :destroy
end
```

However, when I try to delete a word, I get the following error:

> ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column
> words.word_synonym_id does not exist)

Any idea what's wrong with my double association? Thanks.

EDIT: here is the schema of Word and Synonym

```
create_table "words", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "content"
    t.string "slug"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.index ["content"], name: "index_words_on_content", opclass: :gin_trgm_ops, using: :gin
  end

create_table "synonyms", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.bigint "word_origin_id"
    t.bigint "word_synonym_id"
    t.index ["word_origin_id"], name: "index_synonyms_on_word_origin_id"
    t.index ["word_synonym_id"], name: "index_synonyms_on_word_synonym_id"
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Word` is referencing itself without the needed columns. You have to change the line to be

```
has_many :word_synonyms, class_name: 'Synonym', 
         foreign_key: 'word_synonym_id', dependent: :destroy

has_many :word_origins, class_name: 'Synonym', 
         foreign_key: 'word_origin_id', dependent: :destroy
```